# File received and validation

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver, jmeter-plugins

I'm doing performance testing for one web based application using Selenium Webdriver using JMeter so after uploading the file into the Application via Jmeter WebDriver tool **Can we find out the timestamp using JMeter webdriver tool. How much it took to upload and validation completion.**

Could anyone please help me and also please refer the below screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIkps.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can get timestamps for both stage names using [WebElement.getText()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText()) function and then calculate the difference using [TimeCategory](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html) class:

```
def uploaded = uploaded_web_element.getText()
def validated = validated_web_element.getText()

def uploaded_date = Date.parse('dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss', uploaded)
def validated_date = Date.parse('dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss', validated)

use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    def duration = validated_date - uploaded_date
    WDS.log.info("Elapsed: ${duration.seconds} seconds")
}
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)